# Dynamic create array for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Below jQuery code working fine. But I want to add enableDays with response of Json like `jQuery.each(json.available_dates, function (i, v) {
});`

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('photostudio/index/productsinfo');?>',
            data: {
                treatment_id:data.treatment_id,
            },
            success: function (json) {
                /*var enableDays = new Array();
                jQuery.each(json.available_dates, function (i, v) {
                    enableDays.push(v);
                });*/

                var dateToday = new Date();    
                var enableDays = ["2017-08-31","2017-09-01"];
                var dates = jQuery("#sandbox-container div").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: dateToday,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    minDate: dateToday,
                    maxDate: new Date(dateToday.getFullYear() + 1, dateToday.getMonth(), dateToday.getDate()),
                    beforeShowDay: function(dateToday){
                        var sdate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd',dateToday)
                        if(jQuery.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
                            return [true];
                        }
                        return [false];
                    },
                    onSelect: function(selectedDate) { 
                        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                            instance = jQuery(this).data("datepicker"),
                            date = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || jQuery.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                        alert(selectedDate.id);
                        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
                    }
                });     
            }
});
```

I have tried with

```
var enableDays = new Array();
jQuery.each(json.available_dates, function (i, v) {
    enableDays.push(v);
});
```

But I can't get result in created calender.
Full code is added here.
Response Json is `2017-08-31,2017-09-01`
See working code is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikadit/4vnna6vx/)

Comment: And where is this "response of json" coming from? Is it something async?

Comment: Create a working snippet/jsfiddle that shows the problem

Comment: @adeneo It is coming from controller file.
2017-08-31,2017-09-01

Comment: Good for you, but **how** is it coming from controller file ?

Comment: @adeneo I have edit code above.

Comment: may I know or you put what's inside the json response? and json.available dates, what it look like?

Comment: @masterpreenz check this URL.
http://enfolytics.com/NaturallyWhite/photostudio/index/productsinfo/?method=getProductInfo&product_id=1&parent_id=28&totalItems=1&size_id=37269&location_id=37269&treatment_id=2239050&_=1504131646983

"available_dates":[
"2017-08-31",
"2017-09-01"
],

Comment: @masterpreenz
A static thing var enableDays = ["2017-08-31","2017-09-01","2017-09-02","2017-09-03"];

Need to be dynamic with 


"available_dates":[
"2017-08-31",
"2017-09-01"
],

Comment: I see, did `var enableDays = json.available_dates;` work? by the looks of it should be working.

Comment: @masterpreenz
It works. Also, there is some other issue as well. But cache issue is the main thing. It works in private browser.

Comment: Try to open web console / inspect element to see what kind of error it gives you in a non private browser, hard to assume whats going on